# SP - What is the reason to use "using" in WebParts

Tags: sharepoint-server, spweb, spsite

I want to know, what is the reason to use "Using" like this:

```
using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite("www.contoso.com"))
{
  using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
  {
     **my code here......**
  }
}
```

How is the best practice for naming my objects (oSite and oWeb). It is curious :)

Comment: This may help you http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14670/how-to-properly-use-the-using-statement-with-sharepoint-objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, it doesn't have any to do with your code begin run in a web part (or any other specific position).

What really matters here is that you are creating a new instance of a `SPSite`/`SPWeb` object. Since these classes both implement the `IDisposable` interface, and since you are creating the instances yourself (in contrast to getting them from another object, for example `SPContext.Current.Web` to get the current web site) you are also responsible of handling the disposal of the instances you created.

As far as naming guidelines go, I don't think there is any SharePoint-specific guidance you should be aware off, so you probably should just stick to the generic naming guidelines provided by Microsoft, which means you should probably use [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_case) for local variables names like these. As a side note, I would usually add the prefix "elevated" to the variable name if the instance was created in a `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` context, to remind me that any action I will perform on it will be performed under elevated privileges.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for using `using` is partly correct by the other answers. `using` is shorthand for `try`...`finally` and used on objects implementing `IDisposable` (more on this in a bit) the dispose part is done automatic for you. See more here about the `using` statement: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

But why do `SPSite`, `SPWeb` and other objects in SharePoint implement the `IDisposable` interface. All these objects are not only managed code, they are implemented in unmanaged code. As the matter of fact the real logic for `SPSite` and `SPWeb` are implemented using COM+. COM+ is unmanaged, meaning you have to manage all references yourself and clean up afterwards, to avoid memory and resource leaks. So whenever you use `SPSite` for instance you are creating a managed object in .NET that uses an unmanaged object (COM+) and the garbage collector in .NET does not know how to handle that. Therefore these objects implements the `IDisposable` interface which has a method called `Dispose()` that should be used whenever you do not need the object anymore. And this is exactly what happens with that `using` statement, it ensures that `Dispose()` is called on your object and relieves you of memory and resource leaks.

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of using `using` in code is primarily that you don't have to think about freeing memory when your done with the object. If you don't use `using` you have to dispose every object, and that can sometimes be difficult to remember when your programming.

I've seen several occasions where you iterate all webs in a site and eventually taking down a SharePoint server. So you should continue to use `using` to make sure that you don't eat all the memory in your code.

Answer (score 1):

These `Site` and `Web` objects take up lots of memory and needs to be released at the end of the usage. This is also taken care by the CLRs `garabage collector`.

However it would be best practice if you as a developer take steps to dispose/release the memory after usage of the object. This is were you use `Dispose method` or `Using` for the IDosposiable objects.

**Note -** its not advicable to blindly dispose objects, for example you dont dispose a web/site object inside a Event Reciever if the object is reference from the properties parameter.

For more on the best practices please go through following documents

- [Best Practices: Using Disposable Windows SharePoint Services Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Best Practices: Common Coding Issues When Using the SharePoint Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687949(v=office.12).aspx)